# Runnable jar pauses when on another window

Tags: java, window, executable-jar, leap-motion

I made an simple java code to control a powerPoint presentation through hand motion with the help of an device called leap motion. The code works fine in Eclipse, but whenever I switch to an actual powerPoint slide my runnable jar pauses and stops doing what it's suppose to. How do I fix this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [background frames policy](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/api/Leap.Controller.html#javaclasscom_1_1leapmotion_1_1leap_1_1_controller_1a272a235782d654778a1873a28f49a794).

```
controller.setPolicy(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
```